# centering a div in a container larger than 100%

Tags: javascript, css, centering

i need to center a div in the viewport in a container larger then 100%.

assuming it's 160% large, i prepared this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mz0bbz14/2/

usually i would go for:

```
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
```

but this works only when its container is 100% large.

it's solved with this css

```
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform:translate(0,-50%);
  width: 100vw;
```

but the `vw` unit doesn't work on older android browsers and i need to support it. I can't use jQuery and i don't know how to center it with pure javascript.

i tried setting `.div` to half the width of the container, but the text inside the div doesn't visually center.

i can't find a solution. any ideas? thanks

Comment: The inner div really has to be nested? You could easily place it just by taking it outside the larger div, position it absolutely then according to body element.

Comment: Do you really *need* to support those old browsers? If you've upgraded your browser in the last 5 years, you should be fine.

Comment: @MaciejKwas yeah it has to be there :/ outside of that container would be easy

Comment: @AMACB my mom has a samsung s3 with jellybean and she uses the default android stock browser. and i love my mum :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want the red `.div` centered in the left 100% of the parent container that has a width of 160% of the view port.

In that case, you need to adjust the left offset to be 50% of 100%/160%, which is 31.25%.

```css
body,html {
  height: 100%;
}
.cont-inner {
  width:160%;
  height: 100%;
  background: hotpink;
  position:relative;
}

.div {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 31.25%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  background:red;
  padding:50px; /* smaller size for demo in snippet window */
}
```

```html
<div class="cont-inner">
  <div class="div">
    asd
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the left property.

It needs to be in the middle of the visible part of the container.

Since it's 160%, it is

(100 / 160) * 0.5 ->   31.25%

```css
body,html {
  height: 100%;
}
.cont-inner {
  width:160%;
  height: 100%;
  background: hotpink;
  position:relative;
}

.div {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:31.25%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  background:red;
  padding:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont-inner">
  <div class="div">
    asd
  </div>
</div>
```

;

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support older browsers you shall use Javascript to make sure it will work since all CSS solution require hard-coding values.

```
var parent = document.querySelector('.cont-inner'),
    child = parent.querySelector('div');

child.style.left = ((window.innerWidth / 2) - (child.offsetWidth / 2)) + 'px';
child.style.top = ((window.innerHeight / 2) - (child.offsetHeight / 2)) + 'px';
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/9syvq2r2/

Comment: I misunderstood. Check it now.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to place an answer with modified `left` property, but I already see them, so here's some other attempt with `position:static` freeing inner div from its parent

https://jsfiddle.net/mz0bbz14/9/

It just doesn't force you to stick with 160%.

Comment: This is clever, I like it!